# How can I know if a point in the map is currently viewed, based of the DeltaLatitude of the map?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-3

I need to know if a location on the map is currenlt viewed by the user,
For example I have a point 

`{latititude:40,longtitude:32}`

And the view of the map is made from

`{latitude: 32,longtitude:44, latitudeDelta:0.003,longtitudeDelta:0.005}`

When the map zooms in and out the only difference in data is the latitudeDelta and the longtitudeDelta

Eventually when I'll zoom more and more the point on the map will not be visible anymore

Can someone help me build this calculation it will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a coded solution but you can:

get the diameter from the delta (from 2 angles of the map):

```
const diameter = Math.floor((location.latitudeDelta * 40008000) / 360)
```

Then calculate the distance between 2 positions:

```
function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  const R = 6371 // Radius of the earth in km
  const dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad() // Javascript functions in radians
  const dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad()
  const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
          Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
          Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))
  const d = R * c // Distance in km
  return d
}
// add this if toRad is undefined
if (typeof (Number.prototype.toRad) === 'undefined') {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180
  }
}
```

Then with the diameter and the distance:

```
if ((diameter / 2) > distance) {
  console.log('The location in in the map')
}
```

Comment: Thank you so. much Im sure it will be helpfull